# How to translate "Bales" and "Balers Pack" ?

Tags: traduction

I don't speak French yet and I use Bing Translator and Google images when needed.
But I can't figure this one.
How to translate:
 - Bales
 - Balers or Balers pack

Bales and balers as in agriculture.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bales are [bottes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botte_(agriculture)), [balles](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/balles/2), or [ballots](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ballot), here *balles rondes de foin* (hay).

Balers are *[presses à balles rondes](http://www.terre-net.fr/presses/t378)*, *emballeuses*, [*ramasseuses-presses*, *botteleuses*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramasseuse-presse) or *balloteuses*.

Comment: Also, Hay bales -> "bottes de foin" and Baler -> "Botteleuse".

Comment: @GraffitoYes, thanks, you are right, that's the name most casual people will call them. Answer updated. The large round ones are called *balles* by farmers and machinery manufacturer though.